# Constants in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

How do I implement global constants in Parse's cloud code?  I have my cloud code functions divided into a few files to keep things manageable.  I have constants that I need to use across these files.  What's the best way to implement that in cloud code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I created a module file called constants.js

```
module.exports = {
    initialize: function() {
        return this;
    },
    version: '1.0.0'
}

// Some constant
module.exports.SOME_CONSTANT = 0;
```

Then in whatever file I need it in.

```
var Constants = require('cloud/constants.js');

Constants.SOME_CONSTANT; // 0
```